# NginX with Clojure/Java on Windows 10 - not starting up

Tags: java, windows, nginx, clojure, webserver

I am facing the issue that Nginx is not starting up. Followed the steps - also mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41338001/6120175) --> 
I downloaded the .zip file containing nginx-clojure-0.4.4, and unzipped it in C:\nginx. My .conf file looks like as below:

```
daemon  off;

#master_process  off;
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #jvm_path auto;
    jvm_path 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll';
    jvm_var my_other_jars 'C:/nginx-clojure-0.4.4/jars';
    jvm_classpath "#{my_other_jars}/*.jar;libs/*";
    #jvm_options "-Djava.class.path=jars/nginx-clojure-0.4.0.jar;#{my_other_jars}";
    jvm_options "-Xms1024m";
    jvm_options "-Xmx1024m";
    server {
        #listen       8080;
        listen       9091;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    location /java {
        content_handler_type 'java';
        content_handler_name 'mytest.HelloService';
    }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

       location /clojure {
          handler_type 'clojure';
          handler_code ' 
                        (fn[req]
                          {
                            :status 200,
                            :headers {"content-type" "text/plain"},
                            :body  "Hello Clojure & Nginx!" 
                            })
          ';
       }       
    }
}
```

Now I run the nginx-win64.exe as follows:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd c:\nginx
PS C:\nginx> .\nginx-win64.exe
PS C:\nginx>
```

When I go to localhost:9091, the page does not load meaning nginx is not started.

Here is the snapshot of .log file:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nginx/clojure/MiniConstants
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nginx.clojure.MiniConstants
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2016/12/26 20:27:48 [error] 8400#4396: can not initialize jvm memory util
2016/12/26 20:27:48 [error] 8400#4396: jvm start times 1
Exception in thread "main" 2016/12/26 20:27:48 [error] 8408#2548: jvm may be mad for wrong options! See hs_err_pid****.log for detail! restarted 2
2016/12/26 20:27:48 [error] 8408#2548: we try quit master now!
2016/12/26 20:27:48 [crit] 8408#2548: ngx_http_clojure_quit_master, file ("C:\nginx\nginx-win64.exe"), arg (""C:\nginx\nginx-win64.exe" -s stop")
2016/12/26 20:27:48 [error] 8584#8808: jvm may be mad for wrong options! See hs_err_pid****.log for detail! restarted 3
2016/12/26 20:27:48 [error] 8584#8808: we try quit master now!
2016/12/26 20:27:48 [crit] 8584#8808: ngx_http_clojure_quit_master, file ("C:\nginx\nginx-win64.exe"), arg (""C:\nginx\nginx-win64.exe" -s stop")
2016/12/26 20:27:48 [error] 2580#8744: CreateFile() "C:\nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Following is the error.log file after @dscastro comment:

```
2017/01/03 14:24:58 [error] 2552#5560: invalid java content_handler code : mytest.HelloService
Exception in thread "main" 2017/01/03 14:24:59 [error] 3304#4676: jvm may be mad for wrong options! See hs_err_pid****.log for detail! restarted 2
2017/01/03 14:24:59 [error] 3304#4676: we try quit master now!
2017/01/03 14:24:59 [crit] 3304#4676: ngx_http_clojure_quit_master, file ("C:\nginx\nginx-win64.exe"), arg (""C:\nginx\nginx-win64.exe" -s stop")
2017/01/03 14:24:59 [error] 4584#5632: jvm may be mad for wrong options! See hs_err_pid****.log for detail! restarted 3
2017/01/03 14:24:59 [error] 4584#5632: we try quit master now!
2017/01/03 14:24:59 [crit] 4584#5632: ngx_http_clojure_quit_master, file ("C:\nginx\nginx-win64.exe"), arg (""C:\nginx\nginx-win64.exe" -s stop")
2017/01/03 14:24:59 [error] 7172#5508: CreateFile() "C:\nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: nginx is not production-ready on windows.  let's try to add jvm, and clojure, ***what could possibly go wrong?!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple... It cannot find class `nginx.clojure.MiniConstants` because it is not in your classpath.

This class is placed into `nginx-clojure-0.4.4.jar`, so change your `jvm_classpath` to:

```
jvm_classpath "jars/nginx-clojure-0.4.4.jar;#{my_other_jars}/*.jar;libs/*;";
```

... and the error should disappear. :)

Comment: Great..thanks!! It resolved the not found issue. One thing still remains, i.e. it is unable to create the .pid file. Below is the error.log output:
`2017/01/03 14:24:58 [error] 2552#5560: invalid java content_handler code : mytest.HelloService
:::::::::::
2017/01/03 14:24:59 [error] 7172#5508: CreateFile() "C:\nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: It finally worked. I had to add my mytest.jar to the classpath. Now the classpath is as follows:
`jvm_classpath "jars/mytest.jar;jars/nginx-clojure-0.4.4.jar;#{my_other_jars}/*.jar;libs/*;";`